# I am trying to visualise both structures generated by the sentence "I shot an elephant in my pajamas' as described in

Tags: python, nltk, parse-tree

I am trying to visualize both structures generated by the ambiguous sentence " I shot an elephant in my pajamas', as described in the NLPwPython book. 
After getting the structures:

```
(S
 (NP I)
 (VP
 (V shot)
 (NP (Det an) (N elephant) (PP (P in) (NP (Det my) (N pajamas))))))
(S
 (NP I)
 (VP
 (VP (V shot) (NP (Det an) (N elephant)))
 (PP (P in) (NP (Det my) (N pajamas)))))
```

I typed

tree.draw()

But NLTK depicts only the second structure. How do I get to visualize both of them?

Answer (score 1):

They should be read as two different `Tree` objects, e.g.

```
from nltk import Tree

p1 = """(S
(NP I)
(VP
(V shot)
(NP (Det an) (N elephant) (PP (P in) (NP (Det my) (N pajamas))))))"""

p2 = """(S
(NP I)
(VP
(VP (V shot) (NP (Det an) (N elephant)))
(PP (P in) (NP (Det my) (N pajamas)))))"""

tree1 = Tree.fromstring(p1)
tree2 = Tree.fromstring(p2)

tree1.draw()

tree2.draw()
```